# Visual Studio Community 2019 не позволяет создать список (List)

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, list, список

При попытке создания списка следующей командой:

```
public List<int> Items { get; set; } = new List<int>();
```

В разных проектах (Я создавал несколько проектов для проверки) выдаётся одна и та же ошибка:
**CS0246 "Не удаётся найти тип или пространство имён List<>"**

Я впервые пытаюсь создать список в C#, думаю, что проблема с IDE. Накануне появления этой ошибки я активировал свой Visual Studio (он не пиратский, на нём закончилась триал версия и нужно было войти в систему)

Скриншот
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xu4v.png

Как вы думаете, с чем связана эта проблема? Также при попытке создания списка без аксессоров выдаётся CS0246.

Answer (score 3):

У Вас не импортировано пространство имён `System.Collections.Generic`, импортируйте его с помощью директивы `using`.

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло. Мой IDE не видит System.Collection.Generic, выводится, что тип пространства имён не существует.

Comment: System.Collections.Generic - нужно было добавить символ "s". Спасибо, теперь точно работает.

Comment: @questionsaccount данный ответ вам помог решить проблему, так что пометьте его как "правильный", чтобы закрыть вопрос